# Trickle ICE not working in Chrome but fine in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I'm having some problems with WebRTC in Chrome and so checked [ICE Trickle](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) test (stun:stun.l.google.com:19302 server).

It is not working in Chrome with no candidates being generated but working fine with Firefox with generated host and srflx candidates.

I'm using Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) in macOS Mojave (10.14.6).

Can this problem be related to my local network? If so, how can I find the problem? Or is it related to any known recent problem with Chrome?

**UPDATE**: Firefox gather candidates:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote test code.
Chrome And Firefox is not collect srflx.

```js
(async _ => {
  const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[{urls:['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302']}]});
  pc.onicecandidate = evt => {
    if(evt.candidate) {
      list.textContent +=(`${JSON.stringify(evt.candidate).match(/ typ (.+?) /, '$1')[1]}\r\n`);
    } else {
      list.textContent += '\r\<<END>>';
    }
  };
  const offer = await pc.createOffer({offerToReceiveVideo: true});
  await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
})()
```

```html
<p><code id="list"></code></p>
```

Comment: Not sure what mean by that. Firefox is collecting srflx. I updated the question with a screenshot from Firefox results.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but I'm currently in Japan.
In my case Firefox also was only "host".
However, when I tried it now, Chrome also collected "srflx".

Comment: I just find out odd behavior. When I do the same test in incognito mode, it starts to work.

Comment: @Miguel Did you even find a solution to this? I have the same problem. Not working in Chrome, but if I do incognito mode, it works.

Comment: Sorry, don't remember exactly. But I think I eventually solved all my problems by creating my own stun and turn server.